# help with query in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

i would like your help with my query.I have a table employee.details with the following columns:
branch_name, firstname,lastname, age_float.

I want this query to list all the distinct values of the age_float
attribute, one in each row of the result table, and beside each in the second field show the
number of people in the details table who had ages less than or equal to that value.
Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: That's not a question. That's a request for other people to do your work for you. What ideas have *you* tried so far? Edit your question and post the queries you've already tried.

Comment: of course I dont want the answer. And about that I write the word 'ideas'. I want a method or similar examples. I didn;t do anything because I don't know how can I do it.

Comment: @Catcall, I'm not sure that's any different to the large number of questions here where the poster didn't know where to begin? I've even posted a couple of questions where, while I'd looked into it a bit, hadn't found anything useful so decided it wasn't worth posting that info. Personally, I don't think we should be placing barriers for questioners, unless they're just trying to get their homework done without effort. A _real_ question, I'd cut that a lot of slack in terms of pre-requisites. Of course, that's just _my_ opinion, others may disagree.

Comment: @paxdiablo: SO has its own "how to ask a question page". http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask Their opinion: "Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself . . ." Just Googling "sql distinct count" should have led either to a solution or to a lot of material the OP tried and failed with. (shrug)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use OLAP functions:

```
SELECT DISTINCT age_float, 
       COUNT(lastname) OVER(ORDER BY age_float) AS number
  FROM employee_details
```

`COUNT(lastname) OVER(ORDER BY age_float) AS number` orders rows by age, and returns employees count whose age <= current row age

or a simple join:

```
SELECT A.age_float, count(lastname)
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT age_float FROM employee_details) A
JOIN employee_details AS ED ON ED.age_float <= A.age_float
GROUP BY A.age_float
```